# julia comprehension can one index reference another?

Tags: julia

can

```
 [(i,j) for i=1:3, j=1:3 if i>=j]
```

be replaced with ?

```
 [(i,j) for i=1:3, j=1:i]
 ERROR: UndefVarError: i not defined
```

or is an explicit for the only way?

Comment: you can write `[(i,j) for i=1:3 for j=1:i]` and the result will be a vector.

Comment: i see. i had assumed [(i,j) for i=1:3, j=1:2] == [(i,j) for i=1:3 for j=1:2].  thx.

Comment: make your comment an answer so i can acknowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the first variable in the expression for the following variable you have to use two `for`s:

```
[(i,j) for i=1:3 for j=1:i]
```

However, in such situations the result will always be a vector, as opposed to e.g.

```
[(i,j) for i=1:3, j=1:3]
```

when a matrix is produced.

Similarly filtring the result using `if` keyword always creates a vector.

Julia manual covers this topic here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#Comprehensions-1.